# Unitful - Automatic conversion to preferred units under multiplication and division

Tags: type-conversion, julia, implicit-conversion, units-of-measurement

I've just started using [Unitful.jl](https://painterqubits.github.io/Unitful.jl/stable/) to automatically perform dimensional analysis and unit conversion in my code. This does exactly what I want if I add or subtract variables - I work with atoms and generally want data in atomic units, but sometimes have data in other units, such as Angstroms (Å) or nano- or pico-metres and Unitful automagically does the conversion, so avoiding one of the classic bugs in the scientific area:

```
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~$ julia -O3
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.9.0 (2023-05-07)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> using Revise, OhMyREPL, Debugger, Test, Pkg, Unitful, UnitfulAtomic

julia> using Unitful.DefaultSymbols

julia> Unitful.preferunits(u"bohr")

julia> x=1.0u"bohr"
1.0 a₀

julia> y=1.0u"Å"
1.0 Å

julia> x+y
2.88972612462577 a₀

julia> x-y
-0.8897261246257702 a₀

julia> x+y*y
ERROR: DimensionError: 1.0 a₀ and 1.0 Å^2 are not dimensionally compatible.
Stacktrace:
 [1] +(x::Quantity{Float64, , Unitful.FreeUnits{(a₀,), , nothing}}, y::Quantity{Float64, ^2, Unitful.FreeUnits{(Å^2,), ^2, nothing}})
   @ Unitful ~/.julia/packages/Unitful/eFar5/src/quantities.jl:137
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[39]:1
```

As a huge fan of unit and dimensional analysis I think this is utterly *wonderful* ... I wish my main language (Fortran) had similar in the language.

The problem comes with multiplication and division - Unitful doesn't do anything wrong *per se*, but it returns the result in units that are merely the product of the units provided, not the preferred units for the dimensionality of the units:

```
julia> x
1.0 a₀

julia> y
1.0 Å

julia> upreferred(dimension(x*y))
a₀^2

julia> x*y
1.0 Å a₀
```

Division is similar:

```
julia> x
1.0 a₀

julia> y
1.0 Å

julia> auconvert(x*y)^C

julia> x
1.0 a₀

julia> y
1.0 Å

julia> upreferred(dimension(x/y))


julia> x/y
1.0 a₀ Å^-1
```

Now I can manually perform the conversions:

```
julia> x
1.0 a₀

julia> y
1.0 Å

julia> upreferred(dimension(x*y))
a₀^2

julia> auconvert(x*y)
1.8897261246257702 a₀^2

julia> uconvert(upreferred(dimension(x)*dimension(y)),x*y) # More flexible
1.8897261246257702 a₀^2

julia> uconvert(upreferred(dimension(x)/dimension(y)),x/y) # Division works as well
0.529177210903
```

However is there any way I can automate this through Unitful? I could of course provide appropriate methods for multiplication and division of the types I am employing, but undoubtedly I will miss one, so revisiting the "classic bug" which I am trying to avoid; having Unitful do it automagically would be so much better.